# How to use XDocument to get attributes and add them to a List

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, list

I am trying to load data from an XML file and add it to a List. The XML file looks like this:

[image: XML File]

and this is my code:

```
    public void LoadPayments(List<List<string>> list1, List<List<string>> list2)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "RentData.xml")))
            {
                int count = 0;
                XDocument doc;
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "RentData.xml")))
                {
                    doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                    foreach (var dc in doc.Descendants("Rent"))
                    {
                        foreach (var dm in doc.Descendants("Month-" + count))
                        {
                            foreach (var dm1 in doc.Descendants("Payments"))
                            {
                               list1.Add(new List<string>() { dm.Attribute("Rent").Value, dm.Attribute("Water").Value, dm.Attribute("Electricity").Value, dm.Attribute("Internet").Value });
                               list2.Add(new List<string>() { dm.Attribute("Rent").Value, dm.Attribute("Water").Value, dm.Attribute("Electricity").Value, dm.Attribute("Internet").Value });
                            }
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    reader.Dispose();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                File.Create(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "RentData.xml"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
```

I realize the code is very messy at the moment, but I have been experimenting with various ways to get it to work. If anyone can help me figure out how to get the attributes and add them to the two various lists that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If any extra information is need just let me know and I'll try to provide it! :D

Comment: What isnt working? You are using dm instead of dm1 in the innermost loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes you're trying to get aren't attribute of `Payments` element. You need to go one level deeper to get them. Try this way :

```
......
doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
var data = doc.Root
              .Elements()
              .Elements("Payments");
foreach(var d in data)
{
    var patti = d.Element("Patti");
    list1.Add(new List<string>()
             { 
                patti.Attribute("Rent").Value, 
                patti.Attribute("Water").Value, 
                patti.Attribute("Electricity").Value, 
                patti.Attribute("Internet").Value 
             });

    var mike = d.Element("Mike");
    list2.Add(new List<string>() 
             { 
                mike.Attribute("Rent").Value, 
                mike.Attribute("Water").Value, 
                mike.Attribute("Electricity").Value, 
                mike.Attribute("Internet").Value 
             });
}
......
```